# What is a Hilbert-Syzygy theorem example

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am learning about the Hilbert-Syzygy Theorem and have read a couple papers on it but I can't seem to find a concrete example of how it is actually applied.
Can someone help me with how it is used or point me in the direction to finding examples?
Thanks so much!

Comment: One elementary example is in calculating the $K$-group of affine space over a field: any coherent sheaf has a resolution by free sheaves of finite rank, and Hilbert's syzygy theorem exactly tells you that the resolution is finite length. Therefore $K(\Bbb A^n_k)\cong\Bbb Z$, generated by the class of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^n_k}$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can find this example in detail anywhere online or in a book? I don't think I am at the level where I can work through it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, the explanation fits in to a comment: by the equivalence of categories between coherent sheaves on affine space and modules over the polynomial ring, a resolution by free sheaves is equivalent to a resolution by free modules, and the conclusion that this is finite length is *literally the conclusion* of Hilbert's syzygy theorem.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, that is super helpful.